# NetworkManager OpenVPN creates extra/incorrect route to VPN server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networkmanager, openvpn

I'm connecting to an OpenVPN server in Ubuntu using networkmanager.  The connection establishes fine, but a route is being created that routes the vpn server's IP out the wrong interface.

```
default via 192.168.101.1 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto dhcp src 192.168.101.212 metric 100
107.152.8.72 via 192.168.101.1 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto static metric 50
172.16.0.0/12 dev vpn0 proto static scope link metric 50

not needed and incorrect >>>> 172.16.140.182 via 192.168.101.1 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto static metric 50 <<<<

172.28.12.0/24 dev vpn0 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.12.117 metric 50
192.168.101.0/24 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.101.212 metric 100
192.168.101.1 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto static scope link metric 50
192.168.140.0/24 via 192.168.141.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50
192.168.141.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.141.2 metric 50
```

If I delete the route manually, everything is good.  Also, if I run openvpn from the command line that route is not created and all is good....

```
default via 192.168.101.1 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto dhcp src 192.168.101.212 metric 100
107.152.8.72 via 192.168.101.1 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto static metric 50
172.16.0.0/12 dev vpn0 proto static scope link metric 50
172.28.12.0/24 dev vpn0 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.12.117 metric 50
192.168.101.0/24 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.101.212 metric 100
192.168.101.1 dev enxc8f750d7f457 proto static scope link metric 50
192.168.140.0/24 via 192.168.141.1 dev tun0
192.168.141.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.141.2
```

Per the request in the comments, here is the `nmcli` output before the openvpn connection is started...

```
***1 VPN connection
        master enxc8f750d7f457, VPN
        inet4 172.28.12.114/24
        route4 172.16.0.0/12 metric 50
        route4 172.28.12.0/24 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::b0fd:7457:8bb9:645a/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 256

enxc8f750d7f457: connected to Dock (DHCP)
        "Realtek RTL8153"
        ethernet (r8152), C8:F7:50:D7:F4:57, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.101.212/24
        route4 default via 192.168.101.1 metric 100
        route4 192.168.101.0/24 metric 100
        route4 192.168.101.1/32 metric 50
        route4 107.152.8.72/32 via 192.168.101.1 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::9f9c:d780:b443:a93c/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

lo: connected (externally) to lo
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
        inet4 127.0.0.1/8
        inet6 ::1/128
        route6 ::1/128 metric 256

vpn0: connected (externally) to vpn0
        "vpn0"
        tun, sw, mtu 1390
        inet4 172.28.12.114/24
        route4 172.16.0.0/12 metric 50
        route4 172.28.12.0/24 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::b0fd:7457:8bb9:645a/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 256

wlo1: disconnected
        "Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi"
        3 connections available
        wifi (iwlwifi), 04:EA:56:3A:81:67, autoconnect, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlo1: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlo1"
        wifi-p2p, hw

eno2: unavailable
        "Intel I219-LM"
        ethernet (e1000e), C8:F7:50:5D:7B:CE, hw, mtu 1500

DNS configuration:
        servers: 172.16.5.50 172.16.6.50
        interface: vpn0
        type: vpn

        servers: 192.168.101.1
        domains: home
        interface: enxc8f750d7f457
```

...and after....

```
***2 VPN connection
        master enxc8f750d7f457, VPN
        inet4 192.168.141.2/24
        route4 192.168.141.0/24 metric 50
        route4 192.168.140.0/24 via 192.168.141.1 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::ac80:5ff7:3635:5611/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 256

***1 VPN connection
        master enxc8f750d7f457, VPN
        inet4 172.28.12.114/24
        route4 172.16.0.0/12 metric 50
        route4 172.28.12.0/24 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::b0fd:7457:8bb9:645a/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 256

enxc8f750d7f457: connected to Dock (DHCP)
        "Realtek RTL8153"
        ethernet (r8152), C8:F7:50:D7:F4:57, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.101.212/24
        route4 default via 192.168.101.1 metric 100
        route4 192.168.101.0/24 metric 100
        route4 192.168.101.1/32 metric 50
        route4 107.152.8.72/32 via 192.168.101.1 metric 50
        route4 172.16.140.182/32 via 192.168.101.1 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::9f9c:d780:b443:a93c/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

lo: connected (externally) to lo
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
        inet4 127.0.0.1/8
        inet6 ::1/128
        route6 ::1/128 metric 256

tun0: connected (externally) to tun0
        "tun0"
        tun, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.141.2/24
        route4 192.168.141.0/24 metric 50
        route4 192.168.140.0/24 via 192.168.141.1 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::ac80:5ff7:3635:5611/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 256

vpn0: connected (externally) to vpn0
        "vpn0"
        tun, sw, mtu 1390
        inet4 172.28.12.114/24
        route4 172.16.0.0/12 metric 50
        route4 172.28.12.0/24 metric 50
        inet6 fe80::b0fd:7457:8bb9:645a/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 256

wlo1: disconnected
        "Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi"
        3 connections available
        wifi (iwlwifi), 04:EA:56:3A:81:67, autoconnect, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlo1: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlo1"
        wifi-p2p, hw

eno2: unavailable
        "Intel I219-LM"
        ethernet (e1000e), C8:F7:50:5D:7B:CE, hw, mtu 1500

DNS configuration:
        servers: 172.16.5.50 172.16.6.50
        interface: vpn0
        type: vpn

        servers: 192.168.101.1
        domains: home
        interface: enxc8f750d7f457
```

I'm not sure what `master enxc8f750d7f457, VPN` means exactly or how you set that, but it would seem more correct if it were `master vpn0, VPN`.  The ***2 vpn connection is inside of the ***1 vpn connection.

Comment: Can you share with as the `nmcli` command output?

Comment: @K-attila- ...question updated with nmcli output before and after openvpn connection is established.

Comment: Try the `nmcli connection modify enxc8f750d7f457 -ipv4.routes "172.16.140.182/32 192.168.101.1`

Comment: I ended up modifying that to `nmcli connection modify "Dock (DHCP)" -ipv4.routes "172.16.140.182/32 192.168.101.1"` to get it to execute, but it doesn't do anything.  I assume what you're after is deleting that route, and that does work (I've been doing it with `ip r del...`).  But whenever I reconnect that ***2 vpn (using network manager), that route comes back.

Comment: May need to do it with edit mode, and the last command `save persistent`. I think the persistent save is the default, just for sure....

Comment: It seems like it's telling me there are no routes (perhaps why the above command seems to do nothing)...

`nmcli ipv4> print` gives me `ipv4.routes:                            --`